# Install GSIF package in for R in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, r, soil

What are the alternative ways to install the GSIF package for geostatistics analysis in R on Ubuntu 20.04 with R version 4.2.3? I have tried common methods such as

```
install.packages("GSIF")
```

and

```
install.packages("GSIF", repos=c("http://R-Forge.R-project.org"), type="source")
```

But these have failed.